# Meaning of a debug function in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell script and saw a way to add debug function to enable script debugging.

```
#!/bin/bash   
function DEBUG()   
{   
  [ "$_DEBUG" == "on" ] && $@ || :   
}   
for i in {1..6};   
do   
    DEBUG echo $i   
done   
echo "Script executed"
```

I don't quite understand `&& $@ || :`  in the debug function, what is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$@ expands to function arguments in this context, a better syntax "$@" to avoid to split arguments containing spaces

for example:

```
DEBUG echo hello

$@ => echo hello
```

this code is executed only if _DEBUG variable equals "on"

`command1 && command2` command2 is executed only if return status of command1 is success (=0)

`command1 || command2` command2 is executed only if return status of command1 is failed (<>0)

`|| :` if _DEBUG variable is not "on" or command returns status <>0 it does nothing `:`, so `|| :` is useless it does the same as if it was not here.

```
: is a shell builtin which does nothing
```

Comment: “$@ expands to function arguments in this context”，sorry, i don't quite understand this, why needing to do this in this function?

Comment: this is what the function is doing, to answer the why one need comments or specs

Comment: echo $i is the parameter of debug function? if so, i can understand why it did $@

Comment: This DEBUG function allows to execute code only if "_DEBUG" variable is set to on; so when _DEBUG=on, `echo $i` is executed otherwise it does nothing